# replace string with multiple lines or blank if none

Tags: python

I have a few lines of code that should replace a string with a variable that contains multiple lines and if the variable contains nothing, then just replace the string with blank

My current file that has the string that should be replaced looks like

```
"resources": [
        stringtobereplaced
    ]
```

My current code that replaces this is the following

```
with open('filepaths', "r+") as f:
            for _ in range(1):
                next(f)
            for lines in f:
                resourceslist = lines
                print(resourceslist)
        os.chdir(base_dir)
        with open(unique_filename) as f:
            newText=f.read().replace('stringtobereplaced', resourceslist)
        with open(unique_filename, "w") as f:
            f.write(newText)
```

The variable resourceslist has the following content in it.

```
"/home/django/copypaste/cleanup/var/media/admin/9514a8e4-8ad8-4917-a162-6d618b6616d3/splash279/lib/props/barbershop_pole.blend",
"/home/django/copypaste/cleanup/var/media/admin/9514a8e4-8ad8-4917-a162-6d618b6616d3/splash279/lib/props/hairdryer.blend",
"/home/django/copypaste/cleanup/var/media/admin/9514a8e4-8ad8-4917-a162-6d618b6616d3/splash279/lib/chars/pigeon.blend",
"/home/django/copypaste/cleanup/var/media/admin/9514a8e4-8ad8-4917-a162-6d618b6616d3/splash279/lib/chars/agent.blend",
"/home/django/copypaste/cleanup/var/media/admin/9514a8e4-8ad8-4917-a162-6d618b6616d3/splash279/lib/nodes/nodes_shaders.blend",
"/home/django/copypaste/cleanup/var/media/admin/9514a8e4-8ad8-4917-a162-6d618b6616d3/splash279/tools/camera_rig.blend",
```

but when I replace the string in my file with the variable resourceslist then it just outputs one line only. How do I manage to add all of them to the file or replace it with blank if the variable doesnt have anything in it.

Example of current output:

```
"resources": [
    "/home/django/copypaste/cleanup/var/media/admin/089a4bd9-a618-41bd-a09b-f3616c773199/splash279/tools/camera_rig.blend",
]
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation, it's critical for Python. See [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for code formatting help.

Comment: What's the point of `for _ in range(1):`? This is a 1-iteration loop, you can just execute the body without looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating over a file object yields each line of the file, so your loop variable `lines` contains one line of your file at any given time. Each pass through the loop, you're overwriting the contents of `resourceslist` with the current value of `lines`, so at the end it contains the last line of the file.

If indentation doesn't matter, you can just set `resourceslist = f.read()` instead of the loop. If you want each line of your resources file to be indented the same way stringtobereplaced is, you're going to have to do a bit more complicated processing of the template file (maybe matching a regex like "^(?P.*)stringtobereplaced" and prefixing each resource line with the "prefix" group of the match object).

Comment: f.read() does the work actually. Just need to find a way to replace with blank if none. Thank you very much for clarifying!

Comment: @LesnieSncheider If the variable is an empty string, then replace will just erase the matched bit (i.e. replace it with an empty string), so that part should already be done by the code you posted.